# Is there way to map RabbitMQ routing key in Kafka connnector configurations for registering RabbitMQSourceConnector?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, strimzi

We have microservices which are communicating each other via RabbitMQ.

For example :- we have services ServiceA, ServiceB, ServiceC.

`ServiceA` sends ADto message to `ServiceB` via RabbitMq with routing key `service.a.100`

`ServiceB` sends BDto message to `ServiceC` via RabbitMq with routing key `service.b.200`

ADto message:

```
{
"@dto": "A",
"quantity": 100,
"price": 10
}
```

BDto message:

```
{
"@dto": "B",
"quantity": 200,
"price": 20
}
```

We need to publish ADto and BDto messages to another `ServiceD` service which uses **Kafka**.

To publish RabbitMq ADto and BDto messages to Kafka, we are planning to use **Kafka connectors** e.g Confluent provides **RabbitMQSourceConnector**.

***RabbitMQSourceConnector - pulls messages from RabbitMQ queue and writes messages into Kafka topics***.

We need to get routing keys in Kafka because we have identifier (e.g service.a.100 where we need 'a' and '100') in routing keys for identify messages, we do not have identifier in the messages but Kafka does not support routing key instead it uses topic partitions.

***Is there way to map routing key in connector configurations while registering confluent **RabbitMQSourceConnector** in Kafka connector in the Kafka cluster?***